# bundle command gives permission denied - /var/lib/gems How to overcome?

Tags: ruby, rails

From trying to do bundle I get:

```
$ gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.2.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /var/lib/gems
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the bottom of .bashrc

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried executing this as superuser?

`sudo gem install bundler`

Or, you could try changing the `/var/lib/gems` modes using `chmod`.

Comment: This worked for me even on MacOS

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential ruby ruby-dev
sudo env REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM=1 gem update --system
sudo gem install bundler
mkdir ~/test
cd ~/test
echo "source 'https://rubygems.org'" > Gemfile
echo "gem 'rake'" >> Gemfile
bundle install
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that problem comes from the fact that the shell (in the terminal) you are running the bundler in, is not a login shell. Make it a login shell as follows:

> bash --login